# Will having two NSTimers in one class cause them to be less accurate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nstimer, countdown

I have one NSTimer which is my main game loop, it calls 60 times a second. I have another timer which is a countdown, which gets called 0.001 times a second. Is it normal that timer is not accurate? or should i call the countdown timer fewer times per second?

Comment: Your second timer is fired every 1000 seconds?

Comment: @Abizem LoL - well spotted, though I guess he means 1000 times per second. In case my guess is correct, he will for sure get VERY inaccurate results and also possible lag issues within the user interface.

Comment: **iOS is not a realtime operating system.** The only components given (soft) realtime treatment are the audio/video-handling components of the core OS. For graphics rendering, consider using `CADisplayLink` instead of `NSTimer`, as the former runs at the video refresh rate.

Answer (score 3):

NSTimers are not accurate.  The time interval you specify is simply a goal.  The NSTimer will try to hit that goal but the more stuff you have running on that thread the slower the cycle time will be.  Your 0.001 timer is probably going way too fast to be useful and will suffer from accuracy problems.  If you need real time accuracy you will have to track what time the timer is actually firing with an NSDate and compensate accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question correctly the second timer (which I assume is fired every 0.001) seconds is not going to be accurate.

NSTimer has a [resolution of about 50-100](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) milliseconds (0.05s-0.1s) and this can be significantly impacted if your run loop is loaded.

Comment: ...and it's important to note it has nothing to do with being "in the same class."